# TypeError: print() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given ( highschool edition )

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am getting some unknown multiple errors.

```
###Program 11 Create a binary file with name and roll no. Search for a given roll number and display the name, if not found display appropriate message.
import pickle
import sys
D={}
def main(self):
    try:
        no=input("enter the number of students")
    
        file=open("studentsdetails.dat", "wb+")
        for i in range (no):
            print("enter the information of student %d"%i)
            D["rollno"]=int(input("enter the roll number: "))
            D["Sname"]=input("enter the student name: ")
            D["marks"]=int(input("enter the marks: "))
            pickle.dump(D,file)
        file.close()
    except:
        input("there was some error,press any key to continue")
        pass
def print():
    try:
        file=open("studentsdetails.dat", "rb")
        while True:
            out=pickle.load(file)
            print(out)
    except:
            print("error try again")
            pass
def search():
    try:
        file=open("studentsdetails.dat","rb")
        se=input("enter the roll number to search")
        while True:
            if D["rollno"]==se:
                print("the rollnumber %d the data is:"%se)
                print(D)
            else:
                print("no record found")
                break
        file.close()
    except:
        print("some error occured, try again")
        pass
    

while True:
    intg=input("Enter your choice:\n1. Enter data\n2. Print Data\n3.search data\n4. Exit\n")
    if intg==("1"):
        main()
    if intg==("2"):
        print()
    if intg==("3"):
        search()
    if intg==("4"):
        break
```

I have uploaded the cod on `testuploader.com` here it is:  http://txt.do/18as3

Comment: Rename your `print` function to something else.

Comment: `def print():` rebinds "print" from the builtin print function to your own function that takes no parameters. Be careful not to shadow any of the buitlins with your own functions.

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice that, and sorry for asking such vague thing

Comment: it would be a great help if you assist me in the search function in the above code  it gives this errorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nitin\Desktop\nit.py", line 54, in <module>
    search()
  File "C:\Users\Nitin\Desktop\nit.py", line 37, in search
    if D["rollno"]==se:
KeyError: 'rollno'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might can help you,

#### Create a binary file with name and roll no. Search for a given roll number and display the name, if not found display appropriate message

```
import pickle

file = open("student_records.dat",'wb')


#Creating the Records

num = int(input("How many record do you want to fill : "))
for i in range(1,num+1):
    print("Enter the detail of student %d"%i)
    try:
        roll_no = int(input("Enter the roll number : "))
        name =  input("Enter the name : ")
        pickle.dump([roll_no,name],file)
    except :
        print("Something went wrong!") 
        pass
file.close()
        
    
#Display the name using roll number 
file = open("student_records.dat",'rb')
print()
print("Now the time to display the name using roll number ")
rol = int(input("Enter the roll number : "))
flag= False
while not flag:
    try:
        fetch = pickle.load(file)
        if fetch[0]==rol:
            print("Name of roll no ",rol," is : ",fetch[1])
            flag= True
            break
    except:
        print("Something went wrong!")
        break
if not flag:
    print("There is no such student with ",rol," roll number ")
```